# 2006 pt cruiser goes into limp mode have replaced pcm tipm new battery

Tags: electrical

i have a 2006 pt cruiser have replaced the pcm tipm new battery both input and output sensors changed transmission fluid and filter will drive fine sometimes a week then will go back into limp mode i need help

Comment: Seems this an extremely common issue on this model year. I don't know your fix unfortunately but I get these pcm's in all the time for repair because of these symptoms. Did you replace it with a used PCM, remanufactured one or a new one? If used/reman Did you have the calibrations updated to the latest available?

Comment: no brought new pcm at wolfchase chrysler dodge mphs tn brought rebuilt tipm

Comment: Its usually just because of non-active codes stored in the TCM portion of the pcm that causes the limp mode. I would remove and take a look at each wire and inspect the terminals from the green harness on pcm. Perhaps a terminal is cracked or making a poor connection that once in awhile gives way causing the code to get stored.If not there, probably somewhere else dealing with the A/T. Either way if you ever figure it out please post as a answer.

Comment: when i figure it out i will surely post it.so i can save someone else this headache